# Why the text which is extracted from a .txt file holds a blank space character at the end and How to remove that?

Tags: c++, file

I have created a Login system and when this system matches the entered inputs(current) with previously entered `Id` and `password` (using **.txt file**), they both differ by an extra blank space character which is at the end (actually, Idk which character is this but, When I printed it on screen I got a blank), Help me to get rid of this unwanted character so that I can perform a `If-Else` comparison for user entry!

Here is my Code and Snippet of Output:

```
/* LOGIN MANAGEMENT SYSTEM */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
/** CREATED ACCOUNT VIA SOME AUTHENTIC VERIFICATION **/
/* PASSWORD GENERATED */

std::string user_name, pwd;

std::cout << "ENTER YOUR USER_NAME: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> user_name;

std::cout << "ENTER YOUR PASSWORD: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> pwd;

std::ofstream set_user_name;
set_user_name.open("id.txt");
set_user_name << user_name;
set_user_name.close();

std::cin.ignore();

std::ofstream set_pwd;
set_pwd.open("pwd.txt");
set_pwd << pwd;
set_pwd.close();

std::cout << "********CONGO!, YOUR ACCOUNT IS CREATED********" << std::endl;

/*LOGIN*/
std::string user_username, user_pwd;

std::cout << "ENTER YOUR USER_NAME: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> user_username;

std::cout << "ENTER YOUR PASSWORD: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> user_pwd;

std::string verify_id, verify_pwd;

std::ifstream fin;
fin.open("id.txt");

char ch;
while (!fin.eof())
{
    ch = fin.get();
    verify_id += ch;
}

// verify_id.push_back('\0');

std::ifstream fin1;
fin1.open("pwd.txt");
while (!fin1.eof())
{
    ch = fin1.get();
    verify_pwd += ch;
}

verify_id += 's';
std::cout << "verify_id: " << verify_id; /* I have attached a snippet for this output
                                            which is holding a blank space at the end */

// std::cout << verify_id[3];

if (verify_id == user_username && verify_pwd == user_pwd)
{
    std::cout << "LOGIN SUCCESFUL" << std::endl;
}

if (verify_pwd == user_pwd)
{
    std::cout << "Errr! USERNAME OR PASSWORD IS INCORRECT" << std::endl;
}

return (0);
}
```

[image: Output Snippet]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong Admittedly C, but the concept is the same.

Comment: @Yunnosch right.  `fin.eof()` doesn't tell you when you're *at* the end of the file, it tells you when you tried to read *past* the end of the file.

Answer (score 3):

[istream::get()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) returns the EOF character (end of file) at the end of the file.

Change your logic so that you do not append this character to the string you read.